# Meta Spark AR: Using scripting to delay frames

Tags: javascript

I"m trying to delay the cameraText applied in a material inside a plane using scripting.
This is the code that I have so far:

```
// load in modules
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Time = require('Time');

const delayTime = 2;

let elapsedTime = 0;

const plane = Scene.root.find('row_1'); // This is Line 39
const material = plane.getMaterial('material0');

Time.ms.interval(16).subscribe(() => {
  elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

  if (elapsedTime >= delayTime) {
    material.mainTexture = CameraTexture;
  }
});
```

However, when I test it on Spark AR I get the following error:

```
ERROR: undefined is not a function
   {
     "line": 39,
     "column": 30,
     "sourceURL": "script.js"
   }
```

[image]

So, I have the plane called row_1 in my scene and the material in the assets, so I'm not sure why I have this error.

Thank you

Comment: what's on line 39?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `Scene.root.find()` is no longer a supported method in Spark, you need to use `Scene.root.findFirst('row_1)`, and you also need to wrap the call into an async function and use keyword `await` for async function calls.

You can find more info and examples of how to work with asynchronous function calls in Spark here:
https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/scenemodule.sceneobjectbase#properties

Something like this should work:

```
// load in modules
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Time = require('Time');

(async function() { // Enable async/await in JS [part 1]

    const delayTime = 2;
    let elapsedTime = 0;

    const plane = await Scene.root.findFirst('row_1');
    
    // the rest of your code goes here ...
});
```